# Close Colorbox by clicking on background

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using the jQuery Colorbox plugin.  When users close Colorbox I am calling a callback function which performs other UI tasks using jQuery.  My Colorbox code is like so:

```
$('.inline').colorbox({ inline:true, width: '1020px', onClosed: closeColorbox() });
```

This works great as long as a I click the "close" button.  However if I click the black background (the part of the screen which is hidden when Colorbox is open) then Colorbox closes but it does not fire the callback.

Does anyone know how to make a callback when Colorbox is closed by clicking outside of the Colorbox area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){ 
    setTimeout(closeColorBox(), 1500); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event on the overlay itself

```
$('#cboxOverlay').click(function() {
    closeColorBox();
});
```